# What is Visual Studio command "Window.AddTabtoSelection" good for?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Recently I came across the Visual Studio command "Window.AddTabtoSelection". I can't see, what that is good for.

There are also "Window.NextTabandAddtoSelection" and "Window.PreviousTabandAddtoSelection" available which seem to select the opened documents (like selecting a file in explorer).

But what can be done with the selected documents? Neither can I close all together nor can I do anything else.

Comment: Aren't all selected tabs affected by the tab group options in the window menu (like "Move to next tab group" or "New Vertical Tab Group")?

Comment: Well, you can grab one and move them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple tabs selected, the following options under the Window menu will affect the selected tabs:

- Float (All selected tabs moved to floating window)
- Pin Tab (All selected tab pinned)
- New Horizontal Tab Group (All selected tabs moved to new group)
- New Vertical Tab Group (All selected tabs moved to new group)